# DNS query not specified or too small

Tags: python-3.x, dns, dns-over-https

I'm trying to make a python script to test if a server can answer in [DNS-over-HTTPS](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/).
So, I read [this article](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/wireformat/) and try to make the same request but in python :

```
import requests
r=requests.get("https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=example.com&type=A", headers={"accept":"application/dns-message"})
print(r.url)
print(r.headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

Here is the output

> https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=example.com&type=A
>
> {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
> 'CF-RAY': '48b33f92aec83e4a-ZRH', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800,
> report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
> 'Date': 'Tue, 18 Dec 2018 17:11:23 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding':
> 'chunked', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
> 400

If I base me on what's written [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/request-structure/), my request is not **specified or too small**.

Does anyone sees where I'm mistaking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form you are using to pass parameters needs `application/dns-json` as MIME Accept type. Otherwise for `application/dns-message` you have only a `dns` key with the value being the full DNS message encoded.

Compare:

```
 curl -H 'accept: application/dns-json' 'https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=example.com&type=AAAA'
```

(from https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/json-format/)

with

```
curl -H 'accept: application/dns-message' -v 'https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?dns=q80BAAABAAAAAAAAA3d3dwdleGFtcGxlA2NvbQAAAQAB' | hexdump
```

(from https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/wireformat/)